# firebase safari error Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

We are using the firebase 8.2.1 version.
We are developing using react and typescript.
The error occurs only when I view it in safari.
The error is FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK.(messaging/unsupported-browser).
I looked at the following document, but only safari does not support cloud messages.
How can I solve this problem?
[https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/environments_js-sdk?hl=ja[enter](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/environments_js-sdk?hl=ja%5Benter) link description here][1](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/environments_js-sdk?hl=ja)

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/messaging';
import { asyncNotificationToken } from 'apis/asyncNotificationToken';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '******************',
  projectId: '******',
  messagingSenderId: '*******',
  appId: '********',
};

const VAPID_KEY =
  '******************************';

if (firebase.apps.length < 1) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export const prepareNotification = () => {
  firebase
    .messaging()
    .requestPermission()
    .then(() => {
      prepareNotificationToken();
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.');
    });
};

export const prepareNotificationToken = () => {
  firebase
    .messaging()
    .getToken({ vapidKey: VAPID_KEY })
    .then((token) => {
      asyncNotificationToken(token).then(() => {
        console.log('Registed notification token.');
      });
    });
};
```

> a

```
export const prepareNotification = () => {
  let messaging = null;
  if (firebase.messaging.isSupported()) {
    messaging = firebase.messaging();
  }
  firebase
    .messaging()
    .requestPermission()
    .then(() => {
      prepareNotificationToken();
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.');
    });
};

export const prepareNotificationToken = () => {
  firebase
    .messaging()
    .getToken({ vapidKey: VAPID_KEY })
    .then((token) => {
      asyncNotificationToken(token).then(() => {
        console.log('Registed notification token.');
      });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 9):

Sadly [Push API](https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=push-api) is not yet supported on Safari, thus Messaging doesn't work.

Check compatibility before trying to use it.

```
let messaging = null;
if (firebase.messaging.isSupported()){
    messaging = firebase.messaging();
}
```

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging#.isSupported) for details on .isSupported().

There is a [feature request](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1423) to support [safari push notification](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/safari-push-notifications/) on Mac desktop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Where should I put the above code in my code?

Comment: You should declare the code at the top. Then instead of writing `firebase.messaging()` in prepareNotification you write `messaging.requestPermission()` for example.
And don't forget to test `if (!messaging) return;` or you might want to alert that it's not supported.

Comment: Please approve the answer, if it's helpful.

Comment: Does this mean that you can solve the problem by writing something like "a"?

Comment: No, because now you're just fixing it with `prepareNotification`, you also want it in `prepareNotificationToken`. so instead of writing it twice you declare it next to `firebase.apps.length`.
Beside this, you need to use `messaging` instead of `firebase.messaging()`, after checking `messaging` is not null.

Comment: Wow safari sucks! This is how you get it on v9 `import {isSupported} from "firebase/messaging";
`

Comment: @SteveMoretz did you get it work for PWA app? is it working irrespective any iphone device model? is it working for PWA web app or actual IOS app?

Answer (score 0):

Go to  Safari -> develop-> Experimental Features. Enable both "Notifications" and "Push Notifications" or "Push API"
you can enable develop menu from safari -> setting -> advanced tab -> enable show develope menu